# Cannot use DELETE in MERGE

Tags: sql

please help me to understand what exatly i do wrong. Below indicated two script returns error. Who can clarify? Why I can not use DELETE in MERGE?

```
merge into ins_test2 a
using ins_test b
on (a.id=b.id)
when matched then 
update set name='B'
when not matched then 
insert (name) values('S')
delete where id<3
where b.id>0; 

merge into ins_test2 a
using ins_test b
on (a.id=b.id)
when matched then 
delete where id<3
when not matched then 
insert (name) values('S')
where b.id>0;
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

The `DELETE clause` should be part of the `merge_update_clause` hence use like the below

```
    merge into ins_test2 a
    using ins_test b
    on (a.id=b.id)
    when matched then 
    update set name='B'
    delete where a.id<3
    when not matched then 
    insert (name) values('S')
    where b.id>0;
```